Custom font doesn't seem to work
i need to use the font monotype corsiva which I have installed and uploaded to my project but I keep getting font cant be found. what am I doing wrong?
here's what I did
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\monotypecorsiva}{MonotypeCorsiva}
[Extension = .ttf, UprightFont = *-Regular]

\title{practise}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\begin{document}

This is a normal text.

{\monotypecorsiva This text uses the monotype corsiva font}


\end{document}

PS: I am a beginner, so I apologize if I am making a stupid mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please tell us whether you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile your document.

I am using XeLaTeX

You can work locally putting the font files in the folder of your project.

what file names have you installed, do you have a MonotypeCorsiva-Regular.ttf as that is the filename you have specified to fontspec

umm i have it installed as Monotype Corsiva. can you please elaborate on what I am doing wrong?

what filename have you used, The version in Windows is called Mtcorsva.ttf but if you have bought the font from monotype I don't know what file name it has.

Did you upload the font from your system to Overleaf? Is that what you meant by uploading to your project?

yes that's what i mean

What is the name of the file (on Overleaf!) that you've uploaded to Overleaf? Is it MonotypeCorsiva-Regular.ttf? Is it something else?

"Monotype Corsiva.ttf"  this is the file on overleaf, i literally copy pasted the  name here

i fixed the issue, not through Overleaf tho, I got the text I needed in that font on word and imported that particular file to Overleaf which did the job for me. this is not the solution to the problem I mentioned but is a way around it. any other solution is welcomed!

MonotypeCorsiva -> Monotype Corsiva when loading the font to define it.
